# Calling an onclick event from a different Component

Tags: reactjs

I am desperatly trying to make my code works between 2 components by using the onclick event of my modal component to my Avaibalities component but nothing happens.

How can i make the value of my state ShowModal works?

Avaibalities Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import Modal from '../pages/Modal';

class Avaibalities extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    showDate: false,
    showModal: false,
  };
  onChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({ date });
  };
  validation = () => {
    this.setState({
      showDate: true,
    });
  };

  togglePop = () => {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="home">
          <div className="calendarContent">
            <div>
              <Calendar
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.date}
                locale="en-GB"
              />
             <>
              <button className={'button'}>Validate</button>
              <div>
                {this.state.showModal ? (
                  <Modal toggle={this.togglePop} />
                ) : null}         
            </>
            {this.state.showDate ? (
              <div>
                <p>
                  From : {this.state.date[0].toLocaleDateString()} to :{' '}
                  {this.state.date[1].toLocaleDateString()}
                </p>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Avaibalities;
```

Modal Component

```
import React from 'react';


class Modal extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.toggle();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal_content">
          <span className="close" onClick={this.handleClick}>&times;</span>
          <p>I'm A Pop Up!!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Looking for someone to help me,

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not render your modal in this code because I see that showModal initially `false` and to set it as true you call `tooglePop` function as a props in Modal. But render of Modal component depends on `showModal` state so it never renders because initially `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect something to happen here.

To display your modal, you need `this.state.showModal = true`. In your modal, you are setting `showModal` to `true` but it's not different than te previous state, so nothing happens.

Change your  method as follow :

```
togglePop = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      showModal: !prevState.showModal
    }));
  };
```